# OCaml Unix Error

Tags: unix, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I have run into an error that I am not sure how to debug. The error is `Exception: (Unix.Unix_error "Too many open files" pipe "")`. I am not opening any files and only have a single Unix process open. Anybody have some tips on how to debug this?

The function causing the error is:

```
 let rec update_act_odrs ?(sec_to_wait = 0.0) () = 
    try         
      (act_odrs := active_orders ())
      |> fun _ -> Lwt_io.print "active_orders Updated\n"
    with _ ->   
      Lwt_unix.sleep sec_to_wait
      >>= update_act_odrs ~sec_to_wait:(sec_to_wait +. 1.0)
```

where `active_orders ()` is a function that gets JSON data from a server.

Comment: Maybe the `active_orders` function do open files? Don't think on lwt anyway, `sleep` and `print` don't open any files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `ltrace`, to trace the calls to `open` or `pipe` function. Also, it is good idea, just to grep your codebase, for functions that usually opens descriptors, e.g. `openfile`, `socket`, `pipe`, `popen`.

Also, you should know, that the failing function is not always a root of the evil. The descriptors can be eaten by some other process or function in your process.

You can also look at `/proc` folder, if you're on linux, to make sure, that your process actually eats so many `fd`s. Maybe, you have another process in your system, that is launched by your application, and that is responsible for the fd leak.

Finally, from the code you've shown, I can conclude, that the source of leak can be only `active_orders` function. If it downloads `json` data from serve, it should open a socket connection. The fact that error message, points to the pipe is strange, maybe it is implemented with `popen` or `system` functions.